# how to resolve OAuthException: (#100)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use my recently develop fb app to post on my wall and its shows the following error

**Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted thrown in**

you can also see this directly [*https://apps.facebook.com/hack-proof_pages/1gp.html](https://apps.facebook.com/hack-proof_pages/1gp.html)

using two files "1gp.html" and "gp1.php"

**1gp.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="gp1.php">
  <p>message
    <textarea style="width:300px; height:50px;" name="message1"></textarea>
</p>
  <p>link 
    <input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="link1" />
  </p>
  <p>
    Picture 
    <input type="text"  name="picture1" />
</p>
  <p>
    name 
    <input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="name1" />
</p>
  <p>
    Caption
    <input type="text" style="width:300px;" name="caption1" />
</p>
  <p>Description
    <textarea style="width:300px; height:50px;" name="description1"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

gp1.php code

```
<?php 

require_once 'library/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '149865361795547',
  'secret' => 'shhhh seceret :)',
  'cookie' => true,
)); 

     $app_id = '149865361795547';

     $canvas_page = "https://apps.facebook.com/hack-proof_pages/gp1.php";


     //get data for post

     $message1 = $_POST['message1'];
     $picture1 = $_POST['picture1'];
     $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
     $link1  = $_POST['link1'];
     $caption1 =  $_POST['caption1'];
     $description1  = $_POST['description1'];

     // compile the post for for user
    $WallPost = array(
        'message' => $message1,
'link' => $link1,
'picture' => $picture1,
'name' => $name1,
'caption' => $caption1);  // you can also use 'picture', 'link', 'name', 'caption', 'description', 'source'.... 
    //http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/


         $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . ("&scope=email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access,publish_actions,manage_pages,user_groups&response_type=token");

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {

     //getting the userid and some other data for verification 

     //get the user id 
            $UserId = $data["user_id"];
            echo 'UserId;' . $UserId;

    //get the user access token
            $atoken = $facebook->getAccessToken();
            echo "</br>" . 'User Access_Token:' . $atoken;

    //set default access token and profile
            //$facebook->setAccessToken($atoken);
            //$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

     //get the user name and email
            $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            $user_name = $user_profile['name'];
            echo "Name: " . $user_name;
            $user_email = $user_profile['email'];
            echo "email: " . $user_email;

    // post to user wall
            $response = $facebook->api('/me' . '/feed','POST',$WallPost);


    //posting to groups wall with sleeping time support poster.xls


} 
?>
```

***Note:** my app use self signed certificate SSL so that if you want to test this above URL you need to allow my site and store its certificate and one more info that sometimes google chrome shows error due to google chrome one weak point that chrome needs to store self signed certificate in internet explorer means if you want to check this in chrome you need to first open this site in internet explorer and allow my site self signed certificate and store permanently so that its also work in chrome

Comment: i didn't find any error in your coding i also didn't understand why get the error

Comment: The error you get say that you have a problem with the url of the picture, what exactly do you pass in the *picture* parameter? I see you get it from the form the user posts, but the input type is text, what will a user put in there? What did you have there when you got that error?

Comment: you can also try by yourself my pic url is simple like http://example.com/mypic.jpg

Comment: voted down because your test URL doesn't work and you don't say what your pic's URL actually is.

Comment: @GilBirman thanks for your comment :) and i hope you will vote up because i also updated this info that my app use self signed certificate SSL so that if you want to test this you need to allow my site and store its certificate and one more info that sometimes google chrome shows error due to google chrome one weak point that chrome needs to store self signed certificate in internet explorer means if you want to check this in chrome you need to first open this site in internet explorer and allow its self signed certificate and store permantely so that its also work in chrome

Comment: @AbdullahAdam, I voted you up, but the SSL problem is a drag and makes me too lazy to try to help (hopefully others won't feel the same). You should be able to provide the direct link (not facebook.com...) to your site without SSL to make things easier for us ;)

Comment: thanks here is the direct URL http://pakturkkarachiboys.org/fbapp/hack_proof_pages/1gp.html but the problem is that when it try to connects with facebook its show error due to SSL :)

Comment: Ah yes, because you are authenticating with PHP, not JavaScript. Sorry about that.

Comment: hey friends don't need to say sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your picture url, you need to give the full url of the photo not the relative url and facebook should be able to access the picture url, i.e. it should not be of your locally hosted application, try placing a fully qualified sample url of any picture in ur code and check.